# Cannot ssh to ibmcloud instance created via terraform

Tags: cloud, terraform, ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm

I can successfully create an instance in IBMCloud via Terraform. The problem is that after successfully deploying I cannot ssh into the instance.

The version of the terraform-provider-ibm is: **1.11.2**.

The version of terraform itself is: **v0.12.20**.

The terraform code I am using is the following:

```
provider "ibm" {
  ibmcloud_api_key   = ""
  region="eu-gb"
  generation = 2
}

variable "ssh_public_key" {
  default = "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
}

resource "ibm_is_vpc" "testacc_vpc" {
  name = "testvpc"
}

resource "ibm_is_subnet" "testacc_subnet" {
  name            = "testsubnet"
  vpc             = ibm_is_vpc.testacc_vpc.id
  zone            = "eu-gb-1"
  ipv4_cidr_block = "10.242.0.0/24"
}

resource "ibm_is_ssh_key" "testacc_sshkey" {
  name       = "testssh"
  public_key = "file(var.ssh_public_key)"
}


resource "ibm_is_security_group" "testacc_security_group" {
    name = "test"
    vpc = ibm_is_vpc.testacc_vpc.id
}

resource "ibm_is_security_group_rule" "testacc_security_group_rule_all" {
    group = ibm_is_security_group.testacc_security_group.id
    direction = "inbound"
    remote = "127.0.0.1"
    depends_on = [ibm_is_security_group.testacc_security_group]
}

resource "ibm_is_security_group_rule" "testacc_security_group_rule_ssh" {
    group = ibm_is_security_group.testacc_security_group.id
    direction = "inbound"
    remote = "127.0.0.1"
    icmp {
        code = 22
        type = 22
    }
    depends_on = [ibm_is_security_group_rule.testacc_security_group_rule_all]
}
resource "ibm_is_instance" "testacc_instance" {
  name    = "testinstance"
  image   = "99edcc54-c513-4d46-9f5b-36243a1e50e2"
  profile = "cx2-2x4"

  primary_network_interface {
    subnet = ibm_is_subnet.testacc_subnet.id
  }

  network_interfaces {
    name   = "eth1"
    subnet = ibm_is_subnet.testacc_subnet.id
  }

  vpc  = ibm_is_vpc.testacc_vpc.id
  zone = "eu-gb-1"
  keys = [ibm_is_ssh_key.testacc_sshkey.id]
  depends_on = [ibm_is_security_group_rule.testacc_security_group_rule_ssh]

  //User can configure timeouts
  timeouts {
    create = "90m"
    delete = "30m"
  }
}

resource "ibm_is_floating_ip" "fip1" {
  name   = "fip1"
  target = ibm_is_instance.testacc_instance.primary_network_interface[0].id
}

output "sshcommand" {
  value = "ssh root@${ibm_is_floating_ip.fip1.address}"
}
```

Does anyone see any problem with the security rules? Am I missing some additional configuration?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of changes that need to be done in the terraform file

1. You need to attach the instance (vsi) to the security group.
2. No need of an `network interface` if you are defining a primary network interface. In case, if you need one, remember to attach the security group with `ssh` rule using `security_groups`
3. The remote should be `0.0.0.0/0`, not `127.0.0.1`
4. Pass the SSH pub key value `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or create the SSH key from the UI and then pass the key name

```
data "ibm_is_ssh_key" "ds_key" {
    name = "test"
}
```

Here's the updated Terraform file with all the above-mentioned changes. For documentation, refer [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-vpc-gen2-data-sources#vpc-ssh-key)

```
provider "ibm" {
  ibmcloud_api_key   = ""
  region="eu-gb"
  generation = 2
}


resource "ibm_is_vpc" "testacc_vpc" {
  name = "testvpc"
}

resource "ibm_is_subnet" "testacc_subnet" {
  name            = "testsubnet"
  vpc             = ibm_is_vpc.testacc_vpc.id
  zone            = "eu-gb-1"
  ipv4_cidr_block = "10.242.0.0/24"
}

resource "ibm_is_ssh_key" "testacc_sshkey" {
  name       = "testssh"
  public_key = "ssh-rsa xxxxxxx"
}


resource "ibm_is_security_group" "testacc_security_group" {
    name = "test"
    vpc = ibm_is_vpc.testacc_vpc.id
}

resource "ibm_is_security_group_rule" "testacc_security_group_rule_all" {
    group = ibm_is_security_group.testacc_security_group.id
    direction = "inbound"
    remote = "0.0.0.0/0"
    depends_on = [ibm_is_security_group.testacc_security_group]
}

resource "ibm_is_security_group_rule" "testacc_security_group_rule_ssh" {
    group = ibm_is_security_group.testacc_security_group.id
    direction = "inbound"
    remote = "0.0.0.0/0"
    icmp {
        code = 22
        type = 22
    }
    depends_on = [ibm_is_security_group_rule.testacc_security_group_rule_all]
}
resource "ibm_is_instance" "testacc_instance" {
  name    = "testinstance"
  image   = "99edcc54-c513-4d46-9f5b-36243a1e50e2"
  profile = "cx2-2x4"

  primary_network_interface {
    subnet = ibm_is_subnet.testacc_subnet.id
    security_groups = [ibm_is_security_group.testacc_security_group.id]
  }

  vpc  = ibm_is_vpc.testacc_vpc.id
  zone = "eu-gb-1"
  keys = [ibm_is_ssh_key.testacc_sshkey.id]
  depends_on = [ibm_is_security_group_rule.testacc_security_group_rule_ssh]

  //User can configure timeouts
  timeouts {
    create = "90m"
    delete = "30m"
  }
}

resource "ibm_is_floating_ip" "fip1" {
  name   = "fip1"
  target = ibm_is_instance.testacc_instance.primary_network_interface[0].id
}

output "sshcommand" {
  value = "ssh root@${ibm_is_floating_ip.fip1.address}"
}
```

Comment: Wow it definetely worked! Thank for all the insight provided!